# Uniformly Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{n}x}{n^{n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

1. Prove that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{n}x}{n^{n}}$ converge in $\mathbb{R}$.
2. Is this series converge uniformly?

**Thoughts** Tried to use convergence tests but it failed for me. I know $\frac{e^{n}}{n^{n}}\xrightarrow[n\rightarrow\infty]{}0$ from $n$ that big enough ($n=2$ in this case), or maybe I should build geometric series from that.

Comment: Ratio test should work.

Comment: I got $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{e\cdot n^{n}}{\left(n+1\right)^{n+1}}$. I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: Is it $e^n x$ or $e^{nx}$?

Comment: @G.Ticher  At infinity, n and n+1 are indistinguishable

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg it's not help me proving the convergence, and I'm not sure you can say that in this case.

Comment: @the_candyman $e^{n}x$

Answer (score 1):

The (artificial) series of the form $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx,\qquad a_n>0,\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n <\infty $$ are never convergent uniformly on $\mathbb{R}.$ Indeed $$\sup_{x>0} \sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n x=\sup_{x>0}x\ \sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n=\infty$$
For $a_n=e^nn^{-n}$ the series is convergent by the root test or by comparison test
$$0<e^nn^{-n}\le e^n(2e)^{-n}=2^{-n},\qquad n\ge 6>2e$$